# vertical positioning for textarea via input-group in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to position the elements via input-group attribute, one of which is textarea and next ones are a couple of glyphes and button, not really important, i suppose. I want to put it in vertical order, not horizontal one which is provided by default input-group.

How can i do it in the right way?

---

Update: code example here. as you can see, all the elements are positioned horizontally. I want to move the glyph + button block on next line. How can I do it without regreting of input-group attribute?
HTML:

```
    <div class="textareaField  input-group">
         <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3"></textarea>
         <div class="textareaFooter input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>
             <span class=" btn btn-primary">Send</span>
         </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sva6nr8z/

Comment: What you have so far? Show us your code...

Comment: I add some code for example

Comment: Youre saying that you want the icon / button stacked instead of next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, change your CSS to this:

```
.input-group textarea{display:block; float:none;}
.input-group .textareaFooter{display:block; float:none; clear:both; width:100%;}
.input-group .glyphicon-picture{display:block; float:none; margin:20px auto;}
.input-group .btn{display:block; float:none; clear:both; width:100%;}
```

Of course you'll need to adjust margins and sizes to your needs, but the important part is to give a display:block property to both `textarea` and `.textareaFooter`

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b3a9b0z/)

Comment: Here is a working example, if you want to edit your post, @Fabio: www.bootply.com/Yd8Qq5LWKe

Comment: ah, thank you @Frumples , in fact I used his own Fiddle, just forgot to add it, I edited the answer, but many thanx for the help :)